# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto Windows Forms

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema con este codigo ya que estoy intentando cargar un datagrid por medio de un objeto del cual obtengo registros desde una tabla en sql, al ejecutarlo me muestra el error **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto**, ya revise mi código y a mi forma de ver estoy creado bien las instancias, alguién sabe que puede ser?

```
public void CargarGrid()
{
    try
    {
        MostrarNomina objMostrarNomina = new MostrarNomina();
        DataTable dtNomina = new DataTable();
        if (objMostrarNomina.dtMuestraDatosNomina()!=null)
        {
            dtNomina = objMostrarNomina.dtMuestraDatosNomina();
            dgvMostrarNominas.DataSource = dtNomina;
        }                               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }

}
private void btnMuestraNomina_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CargarGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }            
}
```

Gracias por su valiosa ayuda. Saludos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea donde te genera el error?

Comment: Donde creo el objeto de la clase MostrarNomina

Comment: Amigo puedes mostrar codigo de la clase que utilizas para cargar tus datos "MostrarNomina"

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema no del lado del código, sino del lado del diseñador.

Generalmente se crean las instancias de las columnas desde tu código, o si no, del lado del diseñador.

Si en tu `datatable` mandas 5 columnas en tu `datagridview` ya deben esta creadas las mismas, que sepa en columna tirará cada dato aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como se debe llenar un `datagridview` desde código:

```
// creamos el objeto
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// agregamos las columnas y el tipo de dato que se manejara en cada una de ellas
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Telefono", typeof(String));

// agregamos las columnas
dt.Rows.Add(1,"Carlos","2222-2222");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Kenneth", "3333-3333");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Brigitte", "4444-4444");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "Josue", "5555-5555");
dt.Rows.Add(5, "Karla", "6666-6666");

// llenamos el datagridview con los datos del datatable
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema:

```
private void ViewData (DataTable result) 
{
    dgvLog.DataSource = result.DefaultView;
    dgvLog.Columns[0].Visible = false; 
    dgvLog.Columns[2].Width = 200; // Linea que genera el error
}
```

En mi caso, la linea que generaba el error es la que cambia el ancho de la columna. El mensaje de error: *Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto*. Al revisar los objetos, estos existían, `result` tenía `Rows`, por ende `DataGridView` contenia `Columns`, incluso al pasar el puntero por encima, mostraba los valores.

Honestamente no logré conocer la causa, pero lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

1. Todo el código que ocupo para modificar el ancho de las columnas lo llevé al evento `DataBindingComplete` del control `DataGridView`.
2. Adicionalmente, tuve que incluir una verificación pues aún estando allí el mensaje de error persistía.

El código quedó así:

```
private void dgvLog_DataBindingComplete(..., DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
     if (dgvLog.Rows.Count <= 0)
     {
          return;
     }
     // Verificacion necesaria para evitar el mensaje de error
     if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset)
     {
          return;
     }
     dgvLog.Columns[0].Visible = false; 
     dgvLog.Columns[2].Width = 200;
}
```

> > > **Actualización:**

Después de algunas pruebas descubrí que el error persiste, hice más pruebas y me fijé que el error parece ser un conflicto con la propiedad `AutoSizeColumnsMode`, especificamente al establecer la propiedad:

```
dgvLog.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

Entonces, intenté lo siguiente:

```
col = dgvLog.Columns[3];
if (col != null)
{
     col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
     col.Width = 80; // FECHA
}
```

Obteniendo mejores resultados. Dicho de otro modo, el error ya no es generado.